# Should a vapor barrier go on before or after attaching furring strips?

Tags: drywall, vapor-barrier

I am installing furring strips to support drywall and I was wondering if the vapor barrier (planning on 6 mil plastic) should go before installing the furring strips or should it go on after the furring strips are attached.

Comment: On a wall I would say before.  On the ceiling, the insulation will probably settle down around the strips more, so it does not matter as much.

Comment: Why are you putting a vapor barrier on the *inside* of the wall?